# Magento 1: purpose of Magento index tables vs MySQL indexes

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-1, performance, index

I've been working with Magento for years and I feel like this is a stupid question but anyway, I feel like I need some clarifications.

As you may know, Magento 1 comes with several index tables such as (I won't list them all):

- `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`
- `catalog_category_anc_categs_index_idx`
- `catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx`
- `catalog_category_product_index`
- `catalog_product_enabled_index`
- `catalog_product_index_*` tables
- `report_viewed_product_index`

I know what is the purpose of an index, however I'm wondering **how is it better to use index tables over MySQL indexes ?** I'm wondering especially **when should one use index tables in a custom module ?**

Answer (score 5):

Different indexes seem to have different purposes in Magento. It's not always equivalent of a mysql index. For instance, the index table:
catalog_category_product_index holds the product/category associations along with some additional attributes like: visibility, position etc. This table is used by core Magento for pulling out products for product listing pages for specific categories on the front-end. Without this table, Magento would need to do a join either with the flat tables or with eav tables to pull all visible products assigned to a category.

Some of these index tables might be used as temp tables during indexing itself and each of them has a very specific purpose getting into the details of which is hard to contain within a limited scope.

Answer (score 3):

In a broader and perhaps oversimplified sense, you might look at it like this:

- MySQL indices are intended to speed up lookup inside a single column or table respectively
- Magento indices are simply a means of caching data in a single table that belongs together in order to avoid `JOIN`s and the like

Given this point of view, your custom module should use an "index" aka caching table if it's prone to expensive `JOIN`s. Otherwise, you can usually get away easily with MySQL indexing or even none at all. When using your own index table, you'll have to take its maintenance into account, though.